# How to set default width for the <th> and <td>?

Tags: html

I want to know how can I set my desired width for all the  and  in my tables. What happens is that when I declare something like `<th> Employee Code </th>`, it will separate  the `Employee` and `Code` and creating two lines. This usually happens when the data is shorter than the table header. I want to make my table go wider when the table data is long and not go taller like what is happening right now. Please help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enclose the parts that you don't want broken across the line with a `<nobr> </nobr>` tag. The browser will not wrap this part of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Colspan property like `<th COLSPAN=2> Employee Code </th>`
Colspan indicates the number of columns a cell should take up. There is also Rowspan property.

Comment: He is having trouble with wrapping. Not spanning.

Answer (score 0):

use css:

```
table.mytable th
{
 height:20px;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:12px;
 background-color:yellow;
 width:100px;
}


table.mytable td
{
 height:20px;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:12px;
 width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS attribute `min-width` was designed for this and compatibility is good. Except for IE6.